# Printing PHP to node

Tags: 8

I got hook in my *.modules file `php_invoke_preprocess_node` that should print data from JSON according to node type. I need to print it to node content everytime i run it but now it runs only once and print it at the top of the site and then it won't run until I clear cache.

```
function php_invoke_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
$node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
//check content type
switch($node->getType()) {
  case 'nodeType':
    $session = getSession('','');
    $data = ['additonal JSON headers'];
    echo (CallAPI($data, $session)); //return JSON array that i want to print to node but i dont know how
  break;
```

Comment: if it is a dynamic variable you have to use lazy builder service. Also, use ```$variables['data'] = ['#type' => 'inline_template', '#template' => '<pre>{{ code|raw }}</pre>', '#context' => ['code' => var_export($data, TRUE)]];```

Comment: Ok i will try to use it but I never worked with it so i need to learn a bit and i will tell if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

That was a hell of a problem to solve. I had to rebuild my code. Instead of hooks I took a bit different approach and I tried a solution proposed by @IvanJaros but I wasn't able to get lazy builders to work. I found that in drupal 7 there was a `hook_init` that was called everytime but it got *deprecated* in `8`.

The answers are EventSubscribers, using them you can assign any function you want to specific event i.e. loading a page. 

 [Here's](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-register-event-subscriber-drupal8) a great tutorial that intruduce you to that feature.

**Here's my event code**

```
    class MyEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface{

        public static function getSubscribedEvents(){
        // Its called when respond transfer ended
        $events[KernelEvents::TERMINATE][] = ['onRespond',28];
        return $events;
    }

  public function onRespond(FilterResponseEvent $event){ 
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $name = $user->getUsername();

    $data = [];
    if(isset($node)&&isset($name)){
        $nodeType = $node->getType();
        switch($nodeType){
            case 'nodeType':
                $soap_response = new JSonGetter();
                $data = $soap_response -> getUserData($name);
                echo('<script>var JSONarray = ' . print_r($faktury,1) . ';</script>');
                break;
        }

    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi karoluS, as links can go down over time, could you include the essential part of the answer here and provide the link for reference (more information)?

Comment: I don't see how this helps the initial question where you're trying to create a new template variable to output on a page.